# Makefile, Pattern-Rules and Directories

Tags: makefile

I want to write a (gmake) makefile for a compiler that - unlike gcc - puts all output files into a specific directory. Unfortunately this behavior cannot be changed.

My sources are in multiple directories. How do I write a pattern-rule that lets me compile the sources.

Okay, that's a bit unclear. Here is an example. My sources look may like this:

```
./folder1/foo.c
./folder2/bar.c
```

and the output files will end up like this:

```
./obj/foo.obj
./obj/bar.obj
```

How should my rule to compile my sources look like?

```
%.obj : %.c 
   $(COMPILER) -c $<
```

will not work.

Any ideas? I'd like to avoid an implicit rule for each source file...

Comment: You can use the `VPATH` for that =or= you can create `folder1/Makefile` and `obj/Makefile` that will `include ../Makefile.inc`, which should contain the common rules (e.g. the one you've given).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Extracted from some Makefile of mine:

`OBJS  :=  $(sort $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o,$(patsubst %.c,$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS)))))`

Where `OBJECT_DIRECTORY` points to the object directory and `SRCS` is the list of source files (which you can even populate using `$(wildcard)`).

Then in the Makefile, I have:

```
define define_compile_rules
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: $(1)%.c
  @echo " + Compiling '$$<'"
  @mkdir -p $$(@D)
  $(CC) $$(CFLAGS) -o $$@ -c $$<
endef

$(foreach directory,$(sort $(dir $(SRCS))),$(eval $(call define_compile_rules,$(directory))))
```

See [the `$(eval)` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function).

Comment: The eval and foreach functions are a severely under-used feature of gmake.

Comment: maybe it's because of bugs prior to GNU Make 3.81?