# Makefile's eval command does not call user defined function

Tags: makefile

My project has structure with many subfolders. I managed to collect all of the C files into `SOURCES` variable and now I want to compile all the files with the same rule. Since my C files have many different locations I can not just use a simple pattern rule like `%.o: %.c`. Searching revealed the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963802/makefile-pattern-rules-and-directories) to exactly the  same problem however it does not work for me. For some reason my function `define_compile_rules` is not ever called. Why, I have no ideas.

```
TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX = arm-none-eabi
TOOLCHAIN_PATH = /home/kript0n/Applications/EmbeddedArm/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin

CC = $(TOOLCHAIN_PATH)/$(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)-gcc
CXX = $(TOOLCHAIN_PATH)/$(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)-g++
OBJ_COPY = $(TOOLCHAIN_PATH)/$(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)-objcopy

PROJ_NAME = app

OBJ_NAME := $(PROJ_NAME).obj
ELF_NAME := $(PROJ_NAME).elf
BIN_NAME := $(PROJ_NAME).bin
HEX_NAME := $(PROJ_NAME).hex
BUILD_DIR := build


# Compilation flags
CC_FLAGS := -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -O0 -fmessage-length=0\
    -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections\
    -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -Wextra -g3

LD_FLAGS := -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -O0 -fmessage-length=0\
    -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections\
    -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -Wextra -g3 -T mem.ld\
    -T libs.ld -T sections.ld -nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections\
    -L"../ldscripts" -Wl,-Map,"stm32f4.map" --specs=nano.specs

INC = -Isystem/include -Iinclude

PROJ_SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/ble/*.c)
DRV_SOURCES := $(shell find src/Drivers -name '*.c')

################ HAL files ######################
HAL_MODULES := cortex dfsdm flash gpio iwdg pwr rcc_ex rcc spi tim_ex tim uart

HAL_PREFIX := stm32f4xx_hal_
HAL_PATH := system/src/stm32f4-hal

HAL_SOURCES := $(HAL_PATH)/stm32f4xx_hal.c
HAL_SOURCES += $(HAL_MODULES:%=$(HAL_PATH)/$(HAL_PREFIX)%.c)

################ System folder files except for HAL #######################
SYS_FULL_SOURCES := $(wildcard system/src/**/*.c)
SYS_SOURCES := $(filter-out $(HAL_PATH)/%, $(SYS_FULL_SOURCES))

################## ALL THE SOURCE FILES #################################
SOURCES := $(SYS_SOURCES) $(HAL_SOURCES) $(DRV_SOURCES) $(PROJ_SOURCES)
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o))

# OBJS  :=  $(sort $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SOURCES))))

#$(info SOURCES are $(SOURCES))
#$(info $(OBJECTS))
#$(info SYS_SOURCES is $(SYS_SOURCES))
#$(info PROJ_SOURCES is $(PROJ_SOURCES))
#$(info HAL_SOURCES is $(HAL_SOURCES))
#$(info DRV_SOURCE is $(DRV_SOURCES))


######################### TARGETS #############################
.PHONY: all app elf_to_bin elf_to_hex

# Compile project
all: app elf_to_bin elf_to_hex

define define_compile_rules
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(1)%.c
    @echo " + Compiling '$$<'"
    @mkdir -p $$(@D)
    $(CC) $$(CC_FLAGS) -o $$@ -c $$<
endef

$(foreach directory,$(sort $(dir $(SOURCES))),$(eval $(call define_compile_rules,$(directory))))

# Link and compile files(look at generic rule below)
app:
    @echo "Building app target ${\r\n}"
    $(shell mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR))
    $(CC) $(LD_FLAGS) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(ELF_NAME) $(OBJECTS)

elf_to_bin:
    $(OBJ_COPY) -S -O binary $(BUILD_DIR)/$(ELF_NAME) $(BUILD_DIR)/$(BIN_NAME)

elf_to_hex:
    $(OBJ_COPY) -S -O ihex $(BUILD_DIR)/$(ELF_NAME) $(BUILD_DIR)/$(HEX_NAME)

clean:
    rm -r $(BUILD_DIR)/
```

Executing make immediately starts building `app` target without compiling C files into object ones.

Here is make output:

```
Building app target 
/home/kript0n/Applications/EmbeddedArm/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -Wextra -g3 -T mem.ld -T libs.ld -T sections.ld -nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections -L"../ldscripts" -Wl,-Map,"stm32f4.map" --specs=nano.specs -o build/app.elf build/system/src/cortexm/exception_handlers.o build/system/src/cortexm/_initialize_hardware.o build/system/src/cortexm/_reset_hardware.o build/system/src/newlib/_startup.o build/system/src/newlib/syscalls.o build/system/src/newlib/_exit.o build/system/src/newlib/_sbrk.o build/system/src/newlib/assert.o build/system/src/cmsis/system_stm32f4xx.o build/system/src/cmsis/vectors_stm32f401xe.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_dfsdm.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_iwdg.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_spi.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/utils/ble_list.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/utils/gp_timer.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/utils/osal.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/hci_dma_lp.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_gatt_aci.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_utils_small.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_hal_aci.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_utils.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_updater_aci.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_IFR.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_gap_aci.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_l2cap_aci.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/hci.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/hci_le.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/LibProfPeriph/timer.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/STM32F4xx_HAL_BlueNRG_Drivers/stm32f4xx_hal_bluenrg_syscfg.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/STM32F4xx_HAL_BlueNRG_Drivers/stm32f4xx_hal_bluenrg_gpio.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/Interface/bluenrg_itf.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/LowPowerManager/stm32xx_lpm.o build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/TimerServer/src/stm32xx_timerserver.o build/src/Drivers/BSP/Components/L6470/L6470.o build/src/Drivers/BSP/STM32F4xx-Nucleo/stm32f4xx_nucleo.o build/src/Drivers/BSP/motor_params.o build/src/Drivers/BSP/X-NUCLEO-IHM02A1/xnucleoihm02a1.o build/src/Drivers/BSP/X-NUCLEO-IHM02A1/NUCLEO-F401RE/xnucleoihm02a1_interface.o build/src/Drivers/BSP/X-NUCLEO-IDB0xA1/stm32_bluenrg_ble_dma_lp.o build/src/Drivers/BSP/X-NUCLEO-IDB0xA1/stm32_bluenrg_ble.o build/src/stepper.o build/src/coil.o build/src/servo.o build/src/boxy.o build/src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o build/src/stm32f4xx_it.o build/src/synchronizer.o build/src/main.o build/src/_initialize_hardware.o build/src/BlinkLed.o build/src/sys.o build/src/controller.o build/src/buttons.o build/src/utils.o build/src/ble/sensor_service.o build/src/ble/ble.o build/src/ble/bluenrg_interface.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/cortexm/exception_handlers.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/cortexm/_initialize_hardware.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/cortexm/_reset_hardware.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/newlib/_startup.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/newlib/syscalls.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/newlib/_exit.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/newlib/_sbrk.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/newlib/assert.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/cmsis/system_stm32f4xx.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/cmsis/vectors_stm32f401xe.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_dfsdm.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_iwdg.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_spi.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/utils/ble_list.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/utils/gp_timer.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/utils/osal.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/hci_dma_lp.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_gatt_aci.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_utils_small.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_hal_aci.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_utils.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_updater_aci.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_IFR.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_gap_aci.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_l2cap_aci.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/hci.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/hci_le.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/LibProfPeriph/timer.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/STM32F4xx_HAL_BlueNRG_Drivers/stm32f4xx_hal_bluenrg_syscfg.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/STM32F4xx_HAL_BlueNRG_Drivers/stm32f4xx_hal_bluenrg_gpio.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/STM32_BlueNRG/Interface/bluenrg_itf.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/LowPowerManager/stm32xx_lpm.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/Middlewares/TimerServer/src/stm32xx_timerserver.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/BSP/Components/L6470/L6470.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/BSP/STM32F4xx-Nucleo/stm32f4xx_nucleo.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/BSP/motor_params.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/BSP/X-NUCLEO-IHM02A1/xnucleoihm02a1.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/BSP/X-NUCLEO-IHM02A1/NUCLEO-F401RE/xnucleoihm02a1_interface.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/BSP/X-NUCLEO-IDB0xA1/stm32_bluenrg_ble_dma_lp.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/Drivers/BSP/X-NUCLEO-IDB0xA1/stm32_bluenrg_ble.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/stepper.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/coil.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/servo.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/boxy.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/stm32f4xx_it.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/synchronizer.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/main.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/_initialize_hardware.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/BlinkLed.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/sys.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/controller.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/buttons.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/utils.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/ble/sensor_service.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/ble/ble.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: build/src/ble/bluenrg_interface.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:77: recipe for target 'app' failed
make: *** [app] Error 1
```

P.S. I use GNU Make 4.1.

Comment: Could you describe what output you get when running? Some error message?

Comment: @kebs at once it tries to build `app` target and can not find object files.

Comment: This can mean a problem on the dependency of the obj files, and not necessarily that your generated rule is not evaluated nor called. I'd suggest you edit question and add the error message you have, can be useful.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `app: $(OBJECTS)` instead of `app:` ? Seems to me that you are missing basic dependency. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @kebs Oh.. It looks like I do not understand how make works. Thought that `$(foreach directory,$(sort $(dir $(SOURCES))),$(eval $(call define_compile_rules,$(directory))))` will call my function on each source file and that will generate objects files. However thanks, it helped!

Comment: @kebs if you format you comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "main" rule `app` (thats builds all that needs to be build) must have as dependency the needed files (the object files). This way `make` will first build them by calling the appropriate rule.

Thus, you rule needs to be:

```
# Link and compile files(look at generic rule below)
app: $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Building app target ${\r\n}"
    $(shell mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR))
    $(CC) $(LD_FLAGS) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(ELF_NAME) $(OBJECTS)
```